# What is the Sigma Algebra generated by Jordan measurable sets?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, riemann-integration, descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets

Unlike Lebesgue measurable sets, Jordan measurable sets do not form a Sigma algebra.  So my question is, what is the Sigma algebra $J$ generated by Jordan measurable sets?

All intervals are Jordan measurable, so $J$ contains all the Borel sets.  But [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/975384/71829) shows that not all Jordan measurable sets are Borel sets, so the Borel Sigma algebra is a proper subset of $J$.  And all Jordan measurable sets are Lebesgue measurable, so $J$ is a subset of the Lebesgue Sigma algebra.  But are there Lebesgue measurable sets not contained in $J$?

Comment: This https://www.jstor.org/stable/44153840 seems to contain the answer, if you have access to it. I don't.

Comment: @daw: If anyone without access is interested, I have a copy of the original journal volume (from personal subscription) from which I can make photocopy, followed by a .pdf of that photocopy. Send me an email request. My email can be deduced from information in my mathematical stack exchange profile.

Comment: @daw I got access to it.  See the link in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer in [this journal paper](http://gdurl.com/xU6F).  The Sigma algebra generated by the Jordan measurable sets is the collection of all sets which can be written as a union of a Borel set and a subset of a measure $0$ $F_\sigma$ set.  As a point of comparison, the collection of Lebesgue measurable sets is the collection of all sets which can be written as a union of a Borel set and a subset of a measure $0$ Borel set.

And the paper gives an example of a Lebesgue measurable set which is not in the Sigma algebra generated by Jordan measurable sets.  Let $\beta$ be a Bernstein set, i.e. a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that both it and its complement intersects every uncountable closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$.  ([This post](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/tag/bernstein-set/) describes how to construct such a set using the axiom of choice.)  And let $\gamma$ be a dense measure-$0$ $G_\delta$ subset of the [fat Cantor set](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set).  ([This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2993362/71829) describes how to construct such a set.) Then $\beta\cap\gamma$ is a Lebesgue measurable set which is not in the Sigma algebra generated by Jordan measurable sets.

But there may still be unsolved problems about this Sigma algebra, so I just posted a [question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/315051/5017) on MathOverflow about it.

Comment: Why the downvote?