# Are the Borel sets precisely those whose measure is fixed by finite additivity?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets, outer-measure, borel-measures

Let $\mu:\mathscr P(\mathbb R)\to[0,\infty]$ satisfy:

1. *(Finite additivity)* $A\cap B=\varnothing\implies$$\mu(A\cup B)=\mu(A)+\mu(B)$
2. *(Interval property)* $a<b\in\mathbb R\implies\mu\big((a,b)\big)=b-a$.

These conditions fix the measures of every interval (open or closed, infinite or finite), and of many other sets (e.g., finite unions of intervals). **Are the sets whose measures are fixed by these properties precisely the Borel sets, or perhaps the Lebesgue sets?**

To be more precise, define $\mu^-$ and $\mu^+$ as follows:

$$\mu^-(A)=\sup \left\{\left. \sum_{k=1}^n \mu(I_k)\; \right|\; I_k\text{ are disjoint intervals and }\bigcup_kI_k\subseteq A  \right\}$$

$$\mu^+(A)=\inf \left\{\left. \sum_{k=1}^n \mu(I_k)\; \right|\; I_k\text{ are intervals and }A\subseteq \bigcup_kI_k  \right\}.$$

Then $\mu^-(A)\leqslant\mu(A)\leqslant\mu^+(A).$ If $\mu^-(A)=\mu^+(A)$, then $\mu(A)$ is fixed. Let $\mathscr A=\{A\subseteq \mathbb R\;|\; \mu^-(A)=\mu^+(A)\}$. Is $\mathscr A$ the Borel or Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra over $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I would expect the only fixed sets to be those in the Boolean algebra generated by intervals (so not even all Borel sets).

Comment: Consider a fat Cantor set.

Comment: Hmmm, I guess that's not true: for instance, the Cantor set is fixed because it can be covered by finite unions of intervals with arbitrarily small measure.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I see, a fat Cantor set contains no intervals, so it has zero $\mu^-$ measure.

Comment: @EricWofsey Isn't this [Jordan measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_measure), essentially?

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Yes, I think that's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, you've hit upon [Jordan measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_measure). Jordan measure applies to a much narrower collection of sets even than the Borel sets, as the example of a fat Cantor set demonstrates; on the other hand, since regular Cantor sets *are* Jordan-measurable, it's a bit wider than the algebra generated by intervals. In particular, there are non-Borel sets which are Jordan-measurable (take any non-Borel subset of the Cantor set)!

I think the class of Jordan-measurable sets is rather complicated, at the end of the day. As evidence of this, note that even pinning down the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the Jordan-measurable sets is [nontrivial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2979131/what-is-the-sigma-algebra-generated-by-jordan-measurable-sets).